# Display nested data from JSON in textview android

Tags: android, json, parsing, textview

I think this problem is trivial, but I am not advanced in programming. I have problem with displaying Json data to TextView
My Json file is like

```
{
    "person":{
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Jankow",
        "nick":"Jayjay"
        }
...
}
```

another data from Json like address, id etc. displaying without problem, when I use

```
 ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.person)).setText("Person: " + json.optString("person"));
```

I get string "person":{
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Jankow",
        "nick":"Jayjay"
        }"
I've tried to do this using 
`((TextView) findViewById(R.id.person)).setText("Person: " + json.optString("firstName") + json.optString("lastName"));`

but the result is empty TextView.
Question ==> Is there any method to handle this data and display correctly like substring or something like this?

Comment: In your question, does the variable json point to the json string?

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
JSONObject person = json.getJSONObject("person");
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.person)).setText("Person: " + person.getString("firstName") + person.getString("lastName"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this helps but see this.

```
JSONObject person = jsonObj.getJSONObject("person");
String firstName = person.getString("firstName");
String lastName = person.getString("lastName");
```

Use strings in an awesome way.

```
textView.setText(firstName);
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped you.  Peace.